# HQL Select New doesn't return row when a foreign key is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, spring-data, jpql

I have the following named query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "UserFlight.getUserFlightDetails", 
query = "SELECT new com.foobar.UserFlightDetails(uf.flight.divertedAirport, uf.flight.number) " +
        "FROM UserFlight uf WHERE uf.user.id=?1 AND uf.flight.id=?2")
```

The UserFlightDetails constructor is as follows

```
public UserFlightDetails(Airport airport, String flightNumber) {
    this.setDivertedAirport(airport);
    this.setFlightNumber(flightNumber);
}
```

`divertedAirport` is a foreign key in the `flight` table, path=`(uf.flight.divertedAirport)`

My problem is when `divertedAirport` is null (it's a nullable foreign key), my HQL query returns null as the result (The code doesn't even trigger the constructor above), so I don't get the flightNumber which is never null.

If the `divertedAirport` isn't null, I get both the airport and the flight number fine (and the above constructor gets executed just fine).

What could be causing this and how could I resolve it? I tried some null functions like `nullif` and `coalesce` but nothing helped.

I'm using spring boot 1.2.7, hibernate-core 4.3.11.Final

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is the `uf.flight.divertedAirport`. This expression do a JOIN between `flight` and `divertedAirport` but, as you say, divertedAirport is a `fk` and can be null.

So, you need to use the `LEFT JOIN`.

I would rewrite your query like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "UserFlight.getUserFlightDetails", 
query = 
"SELECT new com.foobar.UserFlightDetails(divertedAirport, flight.number) 
FROM UserFlight uf 
JOIN uf.flight flight
LEFT JOIN flight.divertedAirport divertedAirport
JOIN uf.user user
WHERE user.id = ?1 AND flight.id = ?2 ")
```

I remove the references like `uf.user.id` for a explicit JOIN (`JOIN uf.user user` plus `user.id`), because is more legible and this kind of problem that generated your question is more easy to find using this way to write JPQL queries.